# undefined method for active_record error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am a rails 4 beginner who has been confused all day with this problem. 
I want to pull out the location from the user table to use in an api but I keep getting this error:

> undefined method `location' for # <User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f7082b4cfe0>

Here is my code:

```
def index
@users = User.all

if session[:user_id]
  origin = current_user.location    
  destination = @users.location
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=#{origin}&destinations=#{destination}"
result = open(url).read
parsed_result = JSON.parse(result)
distance_in_km = parsed_result['rows'][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["text"]
@distance = distance_in_km
@duration =parsed_result['rows'][0]["elements"][0]["duration"]["text"]
else
  origin = "boston"
destination = "michigan"
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=#{origin}&destinations=#{destination}"
result = open(url).read
parsed_result = JSON.parse(result)
distance_in_km = parsed_result['rows'][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["text"]
@distance = distance_in_km
@duration =parsed_result['rows'][0]["elements"][0]["duration"]["text"]
end
end
```

Here is my view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr>

 <td><%= user.name %></td> 
  <td><%= user.email %></td>
  <td><a href="/users/<%= user.id %>">Show</a> </td>   
  <td><a href="/users/<%= user.id %>/edit">Edit</a></td>
 <td><a href="/users/<%= user.id %>/destroy">Destroy</a></td>
  <td> Distance from you: <%=@distance%> km <br /> It should take you <%= @duration%> to drive there. </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post your `User` model?

Comment: It is empty currently

Comment: So where are you getting the user's location from and do you have a field for it in your database?

Comment: User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "Ishaan", email: "something@gmail.com", pace: "7:30", distance: "8 ", location: "Indiana", password_digest: "$2a$10$zRvssC9RQXIAfCFM6prV
ke3s0l2n5YsHFFzSb9.o1LY...", created_at: "2015-08-05 00:05:05", updated_at: "2015-08-05 00:05:05">, #<User id: 2, name: "IshSup", email: "i@i.com", pace: "7:30", distance: "
8 ", location: "Chicago", password_digest: "$2a$10$1aJPUuvY3Ud14fV/BnFPeeHTUFTqI9/vBn7xH8wacvD...", created_at: "2015-08-05 00:05:54", updated_at: "2015-08-05 00:05:54">]>

Comment: From database here is migration as well: class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :pace
      t.string :distance
      t.string :location
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

Comment: I think the issue you are having is with this line: `@users = User.all` You can't call a single field on an entire class. You have to assign `  destination = @users.location`  another way.

Answer (score 1):

location is not defined in @users (because is an array of users), but in user. You have to do something like this:

```
@users = User.all

@users.each do |user|
 if session[:user_id]
  origin = current_user.location    
  destination = user.location

etc
```

Comment: was literally just typing up the exact same thing...but yes @IshaanSeghal that should fix it for you.

Comment: Sorry ChiefrockaChris, I dont saw your comment

Comment: Its working! But I am still kinda confused as to why...Can you try briefly rexplaining it please

Comment: because with the loop that @papayalabs wrote the code is parsing through every user and pulling their individual location. That way it finds the right user for the action you wanted

Comment: @users is an array of user. And the field location is defined in the object user not in an array of user

Comment: I got it! :) Thanks so much you guys literally made my day!

Comment: On a side not would it be possible to go in the @users array? By doing something like @users[0]

Comment: not like that. You may use User.first. ( destination = User.first.location ) or using User.find method

Comment: Maybe this is a solution  ( destination = User.find(:user_id).location )

Comment: @papayalabs no it gives me error then  saying Id cannot equal :user_id

Comment: I see. Instead :user_id use the id of the user you want for destination. Look that this is If you want a specific user and not scan all the users of array (@users).

Comment: And please remember to check the answer if have served you